# Customize Cypress Mochawesome Report

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

I'm using the cypress-mochawesome-reporter V. 2.3.0 and Cypress 10.4.0 to create html Reports of my Cypress Tests. I'd like to customize this html report and add some additional context like the author of the Test next to the Title and time.
My reporterOptions look currently like this:

```json
  "reporterOptions": {
    "reportDir": "cypress/results",
    "inline":true,
    "overwrite": false,
    "charts": true,
    "html": true,
    "json": true,
    "reportPageTitle": "E2E Report"
  }
```

I already tried something like the addContext method:

```js
  let ADD_CONTEXT = import('mochawesome/addContext');
  
  it('should add context', async function () {
    (await ADD_CONTEXT)(this, {
      title: 'Author',
      value: 'Jack Sparrow'
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only place it worked for me, using Cypress 12:

`support/e2e.js`:

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test) => {
    if (test.state === 'failed') {
        addContext({ test }, 'TEST SCENARIO: FAILED');
    }
    else 
    if (test.state === 'passed'){
        addContext({ test }, 'TEST SCENARIO: PASSED');
    }
}
```